# Specifying 'post_per_page' for multiple post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a post loop that displays 2 different types of post ('portfolio' and 'post').

```
<?php 

    $work = array(
        'post_type' => array('portfolio','post'),
        'posts_per_page' => '8',
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $work );

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            if ( get_post_type() == 'portfolio' ) {
                // My portfolio code will go here
            } 

            else if ( get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
                // My post code will go here
            }

        endwhile;

?>
```

This seems to work fine, but what I would like to do is limit the number of posts each type displays. I've set it so that it limits 8 overall but i'd like to expand this further and limit each type to 4 (4 + 4 = 8 overall).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there I can not think of an easy solution but you have some possibilities to achieve this.

1. Query all posts and make a counter (bad performance if you have very much posts)

   ```
   $work = array(
       'post_type' => array('portfolio','post'),
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
   );

   $count_portfolio = 0;
   $count_post = 0;

   $loop = new WP_Query( $work );

       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

           if ( get_post_type() == 'portfolio' && $count_portfolio < 4 ) {
               $count_portfolio++;

           } 

           else if ( get_post_type() == 'post' && $count_post < 4) {
               $count_post++;
           }

           if($count_portfolio >=3 && $count_post >=3)  {
               break;
           }


       endwhile;
   ```
2. Make two different queries - one for the last four portfolios and one for the last 4 posts

> ```
>  // pseudo code
>  $allposts = array_merge($query1->posts, $query2->posts);
>
>  usort($allposts,'orderbydate_custom_function');
>
>  foreach($allposts as $post) {
>      // do output
>  }
> ```

3. Make a custom call with $wpdb to query exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't like the idea of counting the posts as this will have a significant impact on performance. I'll probably create 2 separate functions and run them individually.

Comment: If performance matters you are probably best of with option 2) or 3). However 1) is the fastest to implement.